# iOS app won't run on simulator since Xcode 9.1

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I get various errors, such as 'Failed to initiate service connection to simulator' and 'failed to attach'. Sometimes it just stops with 'Finished running app on ....'. The app ends up being installed on the simulator, but if I try to open it, it just freezes at the launch screen. I've tried:

- Various devices on the simulator
- Cleaning and rebuilding
- Cleaning the build folder
- Restarting the simulator
- Restarting Xcode
- Restarting the Mac
- 'Erase all contents and settings' on the simulator
- All 3 Optimization Levels in Build Settings
- Enabled 'Build Active Architecture Only'

Nothing works

Comment: Is your macOS device too old / too busy?

Comment: what is Mac configuration that your are running on?

Comment: macOS 10.12.6
Intel i5 2.5ghz
RAM 4gb

Comment: @webo80 macOS 10.12.16

Comment: No idea then. Try to reinstall XCode from scratch, and make sore that you don't have more apps open while launching your app

Comment: @webo80 I just uninstalled and reinstalled Xcode (took a long time) and it still didn't work. I even created a new project and it's still not doing anything. It happens with or without other applications open.

Comment: @webo80 Actually, a blank test project worked. I had to go through an initial error, but when it was on the simulator I tried again and it opened after a while

Comment: I am seeing similar behavior. I can start Xcode, build and run, and the simulator will launch fine. But after stopping the current run, any attempt to re-build and run fails to actually launch the app. (It does appear to install the app in the simulator, but the attachment fails).

Comment: @Questioner sir u have any solution on this??